# Why is Flow/Nuclide showing me a warning "not covered by Flow" in my React-Native component?

Tags: react-native, flowtype, nuclide-editor

I'm starting to use flow and have a simple component :

```jsx
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

const Conversations = (props: { messages: string }) => (
  <ScrollView>
    <Text>{props.messages}</Text>
  </ScrollView>
);

export default Conversations;
```

In Nuclide, I see this warning "Warning, type coverage, not covered by Flow". It's pointing at line 9, where I use `<ScrollView>`.

[image]

Why is that / What does it mean / How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React Native team simply hasn't added Flowtypes to the core components yet.

From the official react native roadmap :

> Flowtyping the core components. Owners: yungsters, alex_frantic. ETA: January
>
> Making the most common components come with Flow types, for a
> better typechecking experience. This should also make it easier to
> reduce breaking changes. Flow already comes with React Native, so this
> is a logical step to further improve the experience.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/wiki/Roadmap/ebdbdc699bc083b98ac7b067465218fd70d30b66

Answer (score 1):

You have turned on the type coverage feature (see screenshot). You can click the percentage in the status bar to toggle it on and off. It lets you know which expressions Flow has types for, and which ones are untyped (meaning you can do anything with them and Flow will not warn you).

[image: type coverage feature]

Comment: So basically it means, that flow doesn't cover react-native jsx components declaration?

Comment: I'm not sure how well, if at all, React Native integrates with Flow. I've asked someone more familiar with that stuff to take a look. It may be though that React Native simply doesn't ship Flow types, so nothing going into or coming out of the `react-native` package will be typechecked.